# unable to set default date with jquery ui's datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="day" id="date">
```

My Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker({
        'dateFormat': 'yy-mm-dd',
        'defaultDate': '2015-12-18'
     });
});
```

The `#date` text box is being turned into a datepicker, so that's working. And the format is in the format I'm telling it to be in. But the default date option doesn't seem to be doing anything.

In this example I'd expect the textbox to appear with "2015-12-18" when the page is first loaded. If I click on the textbox the datepicker dialog will come up and I can enter in a different date but the date of "2015-12-18" should be displaying until I've done that. But it isn't and I don't understand why.

My JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/18000rLe/4/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.

Couple of things to keep in mind -->

**1.** `defaultDate` option would set the date in the `datepicker` `calender`, not in the `input` field. For that, you need to explicitly define the `setDate`. 
**2.** If you use '`setDate`' in the `datepicker`, you don't need to add `defaultDate` as the `datepicker` would automatically pick the date from the `input` field.

```
  $(function() {
        $("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        $("#date").datepicker('setDate', new Date('2014-12-18')); 
    });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/tXyLn/527/

Answer (score 0):

you could use this it will give you the date :)

```js
$(function() {
var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    } 
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    } 
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;  
    $('#date').val(today);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="day" id="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker({
        'dateFormat': 'yy-mm-dd',
      //'defaultDate': +7
      //'defaultDate': new Date(1985, 00, 01),
      'defaultDate': '2015-12-18'
     }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to pass in date this way instead of `Date` object:

```
$('#date input').datepicker({
  'defaultDate': {
    year: 1999,
    month: 11,
    day: 31
 });
```